# Gmail Style File Upload with AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, fileapi

I am trying to develop a webpage which posts the attached file(s) and other fields on the form.  In summary, my page should have the following features:

1. Users can view the files they are going to upload (without doing the actual upload)
2. Delete as necessary
3. Upload to server only if when the users click

I researched on the Internet and found this useful article [File API with HTML5](http://robertnyman.com/html5/fileapi-upload/fileapi-upload.html) about File API and I managed to make it work.  All selected files are uploaded to the server.  But I want to improve it a little bit.

I don't want to upload them instantly to the server.  I want the user to view before they submit and upload only when they click on 'Upload all files now'.

The problem is that I don't know how to loop all the selected files when the user clicks on 'Upload all files now' button.  I couldn't manage to re-access all the files which are already selected by the user.

[image]

In the example, all files come from **evt.dataTransfer.files**.  But it's undefined when I click the button.  Since my code is almost exactly same to codes in the Example, I will post only the important part.

```
dropArea.addEventListener("drop", function (evt) {
            traverseFiles(evt.dataTransfer.files);
            this.className = "";
            evt.preventDefault();
            evt.stopPropagation();
        }, false);


        $('#btnUploadAll').click(function (evt) {

            for (x in evt.dataTransfer.files) {

                var file = filesToUpload[x];

                //do the upload script to server.
                //xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            }
        });
```

My question is how I could get access to the pre-selected files when the user clicks on the 'Upload all files now' button?

Comment: use change() instead of click() and reach the files as `evt.target.files`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second event is a click event, it just contains all about the click, it will NOT contain anything about files which is contained in the first event.

So what you probably should do is: create a shared variable, in the 1st event set it, and in the second event read it. like the below code shows:

```
var filesInQueue = []; // shared variable
dropArea.addEventListener("drop", function (evt) {
    traverseFiles(evt.dataTransfer.files);
    filesInQueue = filesInQueue.concat(Array.from(evt.dataTransfer.files)); // set to the shared variable
    this.className = "";
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
}, false);


    $('#btnUploadAll').click(function (evt) {

        for (x in filesInQueue) { // read from shared variable

            var file = filesToUpload[x];

            //do the upload script to server.
            //xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        }
    });
```

Comment: Does it eat the browser memories?  If there are 5 MB x 10 files, is it going to take 50 MBs?

Comment: No, so far it is just a file reference, you can use FileRead to load it to memory.